# javascript click event not firing action

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page load, I have a search box that, once used, populates a div with multiple images. The javascript from the search uses this function to append all images into the div

```
   function appendSomeItems(url, id, name, style) {
        return '<div><div class="md-card md-card-hover">         <div id="getImage" class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content"> <img class ="uk-align-center imageClick"></a>                               <div class="gallery_grid_image_caption">                                   <span class="gallery_image_title uk-text-truncate">' + name + '</span> <span>' + style + '</span> </div></div></div></div>';
    }
```

This works perfectly. Now I'm trying to make it so that when I click any one of the images it triggers an action (in this case a console log)

```
    $('.imageClick').click(function handleImage() {
        console.log(good);
    });
```

However, it does nothing. No error but no console log.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to add the handler after the image is attached to the dom. ie run ``` $('.imageClick').click(function handleImage() {
        console.log(good);
    });``` after the images are added

Comment: is good a variable? If not it should be wrapped in quotes console.log('good');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in order to bind an event to dynamically created elements:

This approach uses `document` as the parent element, however, a good practice is to use the closest parent element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.imageClick', function handleImage() {
    console.log(good);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach *event* on dynamically created element. This will allow attaching the *event* to the elements that are added to the *body* at a **later** time:

```
$('body').on('click', '.imageClick' function handleImage() {
  console.log(good);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `$(".imageClick").click()` before you dynamically create the items.

This means that jQuery doesn't actually bind the `click` listener to the items, since when `$(".imageClick").click()` is run, the elements don't actually exist yet.

Try this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".imageClick", function handleImage() {
    console.log("good");
});
```

Also see this post for more information: [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)